# Warning "shift count >= width of type" with Emscripten

Tags: c, emscripten

I got some older code in C, which compiles with gcc without warnings, but if I am trying to compile it to wasm with Emscripten, i get the warning:
`warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]`

The code is:
`SomeVariable = ((unsigned long) x << 32) / (unsigned long) y`
`SomeVariable` is an unsigned int, x and y are int.

The result also does not look like it should and like the original application in C, so I don't think I can ignore the warning.

I already tried to compile it with the `-s WASM_BIGINT` flag. It makes no difference.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `unsigned long` is larger than 32 bits. And it looks like emscripten defines it as a 32bit type while your native compiler treats them as 64bit integer types. If you want a 64bit type then you should use `uint64_t` instead

Answer (score 2):

This code is making an assumption about the size of an `unsigned long`.

On x86-64 Linux under gcc, an `unsigned long` is 64 bits in size, so the shift is fine.  The compiler you're using however apparently has `unsigned long` at 32 bits in size, in which case a left shift of 32 in invalid.  This is spelled out in section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding bitwise shift operators:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
> of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand. If  the
> value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or is greater than or
> equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
> undefined.

The code would be to be modified to change any instances of `unsigned long` to either `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation and yes, that solved it.